# pass tickers to apply function to calculate beta in r

Tags: r, apply, finance

I would like to calculate Beta for a bunch of stocks without having to manually set up the equation for each stock.

Below is some sample code on which I would like to pass the names of the tickers to the x paramater in the cov() function while keeping the y and var() function variable constant:

```
ret <- c(1,2,1,3,1,4,5,10)
ret2 <- 2*ret
ret3 <- 2.5*ret
all_ret <- as.data.frame(cbind(ret,ret2, ret3))
ticks <- colnames(all_ret)

beta1 <- cov(x = all_ret$ret3, y = all_ret$ret) / var(all_ret$ret)
```

Is there a way to complete this with an apply function? something like:

```
sapply(ticks, function(x)
       cov(x = all_ret$x, y = all_ret$ret) / var(all_ret$ret)
```

Please let me know how I can do this or if there is an easier way to do this, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
beta2 <- cov(x = all_ret, y = all_ret$ret) / var(all_ret$ret)
```

Comment: Thanks! would you happen to know how to complete something like that using apply?

Comment: apply(all_ret[,-1], 2, function(x){
      cov(x = x, y = all_ret$ret) / var(all_ret$ret)
    })

Comment: Would you also happen to know how to cycle through such that there is a matrix of each beta related to each other? So if i wanted to additionally see the beta of ret2 to ret3 for example, but on a larger scale

Comment: If you want a correlation matrix, you should just try beta1 <- cor(x = all_ret). This returns an N*N matrix where N is the number of columns (3 in this case). Note that what you have written is slightly different from correlation. Not sure if this was a typo or intentional. The denominator should be sd(variable1)*sd(variable2) for correlation.

Comment: Got it, yes I understand the correlation matrix. I'm looking for to create a beta matrix.